# Translation of Delete Selected Documents Action

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

in the "delete selected documents" action it is possible to specify a confirm message, so i can tranlsate this message in every language.
But, if no document was selected, a dialog appears with the message "Please select one or more documents to delete.".
Is there any way to translate this message?

Thanks Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some instructions on setting up translation in XPages:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/UsingLocalizationOptions.htm

you can use this with a  action. What happens is you will have a property file with strings, these will be translated and then the correct one will be used. something like:

```
<xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:confirm>
                <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    //where "strings" is a variable pointing to the resource bundle
                    strings.getString("confirm.message.delete");
                }]]></xp:this.message>
            </xp:confirm>

            ... delete code ...
        </xp:actionGroup>
    </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: I know, but if no document is selected, the standard message "Please select one or more documents to delete." ist displayed, i cannot change this message anywhere i think....

Comment: a lot of the inbuilt messages do translate if you enable the settings as mentioned in the link. failing that it would be up to to ensure one is selected. A simple script running as the first part of the delete button could check is there a document open / selected. You could also use the <xp:actionGroup> property "condition" to decide if it is executed. Have one that deletes if there is a doc and one that displays an error message if not